# Magento 1.9.1 Setting Default Value for Options

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, attribute-options

How can I set a default value if the radio buttons in the Associated Products doesn't appear anymore.

According to the screenshot here you can select a default option by ticking one of the radio buttons beside the option:
[image: Selecting a default option via radio buttons]
SOURCE: http://icebergcommerce.com/software/blog/iss/article/magento-configurable-products-setting-default-value-for-options/

As shown in the screenshot above, you can select a default option by ticking one of the radio buttons beside the options. But now the radio buttons are gone. Below is the current screenshot of Magento 1.9.1 Associated Products tab of a Configurable Product:
[image: Magento 1.9.1 associated products tab]

The question is, how can I select a default option if the radio buttons no longer exist?

Comment: i want to set a default value for each attribute, i dont have any idea.anyone please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `default` radio button is not a standard magento feature. Maybe you had some extension that is not available anymore.
But I can recommend you [this free extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher). Among a lot of things it does something similar to what you need. It doesn't allow you to set a default value for each attribute, but it allows you to set a default configuration for the configurable product. So you can select one of the simple products to be selected by default when the configurable product page is loaded.
Something like this:
[image]

The full documentation of the extension [can be found here](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher/wiki)

Comment: this extension https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher  is not working

Comment: @JenithSamuel "Not working" means nothing. And on a side note, this post was written 2 years ago. In the mean time the extension is discontinued. This does not mean it is not working. It means I will not offer support for it anymore.